# Error out on a block of code in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to break and error out on a looped block of code, when of any of the commands in the loop return 1. I would like to do this without a sub-shell.

```
while read file; do

   command_one_that_might_error_out;
   command_two_that_might_error_out;
   command_three_that_might_error_out;

done < <(ls -1 .) || echo "something bad when of the commands ran happened";
```

Can any one please provide insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
err_val=0
while read file; do

    command_one_that_might_error_out || { err_val=$?; break; }
    command_two_that_might_error_out || { err_val=$?; break; }
    command_three_that_might_error_out || { err_val=$?; break; }

done < <(ls -1 .)

if [ $err_val -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "something bad happened"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `set -e` at the top of your script.  While you're at it `set -u` is good bash hygiene in general.

Comment: I can't see `-w` in the `man` page of Bash 4.1.5, or in a [Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22set+-w%22+bash). Did you perhaps mean `pipefail` or `noclobber`?

Comment: Right l0b0, my mistake - I cross-pollinated with Perl's -w.

Answer (score 1):

You could put `|| break` at the end of each each command, however `break` returns 0 so your final `|| echo "something bad happened"` will not execute.

You can use `break 0`, and `break` will exit with a non-zero code, but it will also write an error (which could redirect away). You can propagate the error code through a global variable as shown in Gordon Davisson's answer.

You can put the `break` command in a function to make this a little cleaner and capture the error_code too:

```
break_fail() { break 0 2>/dev/null ; }
break_error() { error_code=$? ; break 0 2>/dev/null ; }

error_code=0
while read file; do
   command_one_that_might_error_out || break_error
   command_two_that_might_error_out || break_error
   command_three_that_might_error_out || break_error
done < <(ls -1 .) || echo "something bad happened: Error $error_code"
```

That does not tell you which command returned the error though.

If you need to handle specific error codes, I'd suggest handling them inline in the loop and breaking out with break_fail.

Comment: thank you very much this is very good. I think the one that pass on the error helps me a bit more. wish I could mark both answers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably use `$?`, which is the return value of the last command. So you'd add

```
if [[ "$?" = "1" ]]; then
    break
fi
```

after each of the commands.

Comment: I'm afraid this anti-idiom screams "I am not a good shell programmer", with the possible exception of situations where you specifically want to break only on error code 1, but pass all other error codes as success.  (Even then, I'd use `case`, and / or try to refactor the loop.)